# Is there a better rest endpoint for downloading file contents?

Tags: rest-api, force.com, restresource

I'm trying to use https://[domain]/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/ to download files (lightning files not attachments) from salesforce and it works sometimes and I can get it to work in postman be in some cases it returns a 200 status but the contents are the following:

"https://[domain]/ex/errorduringprocessing.jsp"

The weird thing is that I can produce this error in postman if I leave it for a while and try to execute the request without getting a new token so it seems to be related to the tokens somehow. Does anyone know why this might happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a blob (binary data), you can use the [SObject Blob Retrieve](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_sobject_blob_retrieve.htm) rest API call. This would be the preferred mechanism for doing so. The other URI is meant for UI downloads, not API calls.