# Download docx file from Salesforce file object

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-salesforce

I am trying to download a docx file from salesforce and create a pdf file out of it using node js. I have stored the docx file in Salesforce file object and i am passing a json. The .docx file contains a merge field {accname}. When i am running the node application , the file is getting downloaded but it gets corrupted and its not opening. The node lib which i am using is **easy-template-x**. Is there anything which i am doing wrong.

```
C:\Users\hp\Documents\Node\node_modules\easy-template-x\dist\cjs\easy-template-x.js:3453
      throw new MalformedFileError('docx');
            ^

MalformedFileError: Malformed file detected. Make sure the file is a valid docx file.
```

Below is my node code -

```
import sf from 'jsforce';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import https from 'https';
const fileId = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
var user = 'XYZ@salesforce.learning.com';
var pass = 'XXXXXXXXX';
var securityToken = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

var conn = new sf.Connection({
    loginUrl : 'https://test.salesforce.com'
});
conn.login(user, pass + securityToken, function (err, userInfo) {
    if (err) { return console.error(err); }
    console.log(conn.accessToken);
    console.log(conn.instanceUrl);
    console.log("User ID: " + userInfo.id);
    console.log("Org ID: " + userInfo.organizationId);
    downloadFile(conn);

});

function downloadFile(conn) {
    console.log('download called')
    const options = {
        hostname: 'lwc.my.salesforce.com',
        port: 443,
        path: '/services/data/v51.0/sobjects/ContentVersion/' + fileId + '/VersionData',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
            'Authorization': 'OAuth ' + conn.accessToken
        }
    }

    https.get(options, (resp) => {
        let data = '';

        // A chunk of data has been received.
        resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
            //console.log('chunk');
            data += chunk;

            fs.appendFile('template.docx', chunk, function (err) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log('chunk updated');
            });

        });

        // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
        resp.on('end', () => {
            console.log('data downloaded');
        });

    }).on("error", (err) => {
        console.log("Error: " + err.message);
    });
}
```

Comment: what did you "console.log(chunk)" display ?

Comment: just checked. i am getting (chunk[{"errorCode":"NOT_FOUND","message":"The requested resource does not exist"}])

Comment: Well that's for sure not a valid docx file :) You might want to check this link : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/257346/is-there-a-better-rest-endpoint-for-downloading-file-contents